# Drag and Drop Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, drag-n-drop

A documentação do `fullcalendar` é bem resumida e estou com problema para codificar o Drag and Drop. Alguém poderia dar uma luz de como iniciar essa função?

```
eventDrop:function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
   alert('ok');
}
```

Estou ainda desenvolvendo o código, porem a chamada acima não é executada quando rodo o calendário.

Comment: Vanderlei coloque o código que vc já tem e explique exatamente o problema que vc está tendo. Perguntar aleatóriamente assim fica difícil de te dar uma resposta precisa. Seja mais claro no que vc precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o seu caso, mas espero que ajude. Eu uso o fullcalendar pelo primeng, em um projeto Angular. Para o evento em questão chamo uma função:

```
(onEventDrop)="reschedule($event)"
```

E a minha função:

```
    reschedule(event) {

      if ((addHours(event.event.start._d, 3).getTime() > addHours(new Date(), 1).getTime())) { //
        if (this.notHaveConflicts(addHours(event.event.start._d, 3), addHours(event.event.end._d, 3), event.event.id)) {
          // console.log('nao');

          this.event = event.event;
          this.event.startdb = this.dateToStringDB(addHours(event.event.start._d, 3));
          this.event.enddb = this.dateToStringDB(addHours(event.event.end._d, 3));
          this.event.status = 3;
          this.event.cancel_reason = result.reason;
          delete this.event.source;

          // console.log(this.event);

          this.toggle_events = this._eventsService.updateEvent(this.event).subscribe(
            response => {
              if (response.return) {
                // evento atualizado
              } else {
                // erro no banco/API
                event.revertFunc();
              }
            },
            err => {
              // erro no banco
              event.revertFunc();
            }
          );

          this.reRender();

        } else {
          // teve conflito
          event.revertFunc();
        }
      } else {
        event.revertFunc();
        this._toastrService.error(this._translateService.instant('Agenda.IntervalError'),
          this._translateService.instant('Error.Err'));
      }
    }
```

Nesse projeto, o evento é entre 2 pessoas, entao eu checo os horarios na API, caso eles colidam, chamo a função:

```
revertFunc();
```

e o meu evento volta pro exato lugar onde estava. O próprio fullcalendar ja guarda o local anterior para voltar, então no meu caso foi só chama-la que funcionou! =D

Espero ter ajudado!